# How do I import a PNG as a TileMill layer?

Tags: leaflet, tilemill

I want to use the [NASA "Blue Marble"](http://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view.php?id=74218) images as the basis of a map tile set for a [Leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com/) map.  It seems like using TileMill is the easiest way of building up my tiles, and opens a lot of options down the road.  However, it doesn't appear that I can import a plain "PNG" file as a layer.  PNG files don't normally apper as a file data source, and when I force it, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------
TileMill Error
---------------------------
[tilemill] [tilemill] problem loading datasource
Error: Unable to determine SRS for layer  "world" at C:\Users\jklemmack\Desktop\world.200412.3x21600x10800.png
[tilemill]     at Function.resolved.srs (C:\Program Files (x86)\TileMill-v0.10.1\tilemill\node_modules\millstone\lib\millstone.js:785:37)
[tilemill]     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\TileMill-v0.10.1\tilemill\node_modules\step\lib\step.js:51:23)
[tilemill]     at Function.resolved.Layer.forEach.name (C:\Program Files (x86)\TileMill-v0.10.1\tilemill\node_modules\millstone\lib\millstone.js:716:29)
[tilemill]     at next (C:\Program Files (x86)\TileMill-v0.10.1\tilemill\node_modules\step\lib\step.js:51:23)
[tilemill]     at Step (C:\Program Files (x86)\TileMill-v0.10.1\tilemill\node_modules\step\lib\step.js:122:3)
[tilemill]     at resolved.srs (C:\Program Files (x86)\TileMill-v0.10.1\tilemill\node_modules\millstone\lib\millstone.js:712:21)
[tilemill]     at Object.fs.exists [as oncomplete] (fs.js:91:19)

Please report this to https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill/issues
```

I attempt to specify the SRS as WGS84 (per NASA's readme) and I get:

```
Could not create datasource. No plugin found for type 'undefined' (searched in: C:\Program Files (x86)\TileMill-v0.10.1\tilemill\node_modules\mapnik\lib\mapnik\lib\mapnik\input)
```

Any help?  Is this even possible?  Do I have to slice up the PNG with some other tool?

Answer (score 1):

PNGs aren't, in themselves, geographic, so TileMill wouldn't know where to put the image on the world: it's just an image, without any coordinates or 'reference system'. The best route would be to download and use a [GeoTIFF version of Blue Marble instead](http://neo.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/view.php?datasetId=BlueMarbleNG-TB).